# python networkx get unique matching combinations

Tags: python, graph, networkx, matching

I have a graph of nodes that are potential duplicates of items and I'm trying to find all possible combinations of matches. If two nodes are connected, that means they are potentially the same item, but no node can be matched more than once.

For example, if I take the following simple graph:

```
T = nx.Graph()

T.add_edge('A','B')
T.add_edge('A','C')
T.add_edge('B','D')
T.add_edge('D','A')
```

[image]

In this example my outputs could either be:

```
[{A:B},{A:C,B:D},{A:D}]
```

How can I develop a list of unique combinations? Some of the graphs have ~20 nodes, so brute forcing through all combinations is out.

Comment: Wait, so why are `A:C` and `B:D` duplicates?

Comment: Anything that is connected is a potential duplicate (that is what the edges denote). But there can only be one "actual" duplication per node. That would say that A is a duplicate of C and B is a duplicate of D. In the other output, A is a duplicate of D, but therefore B and C must be unique because all of the nodes they potentially connect to are already used. Make sense?

Comment: Can the same pair be in two different unique combos? i.e., `[{A:B,C:D},{A:B,E:F}]`

Comment: yes, but within each "trial" each node can be used only once. Imagine these are people being identified from different datasets. If A = B, then I can't match any more because A and B are already matched and C and D aren't connected. In a new trial though if I match A to C, then B can also match to D.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that what you are looking for is to find matchings of G, i.e., sets of edges where no two edges share a common vertex.
In particular, you are looking for *maximal matchings* of G.

Networkx offers the function [maximal_matching](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/networkx-1.9.1/_modules/networkx/algorithms/matching.html#maximal_matching). You may extend this function to obtain all the maximal matchings.
One way to do it may be the following. You start with a list of partial matchings, each made by an edge. Each partial matching is then extended until it becomes a maximal one, i.e., until it cannot be extended to a matching of larger cardinality.

If a partial matching *m* can be extended to a larger one using an edge *(u,v)*, then *m'=m ∪ {(u,v)}* is added to the list of partial matchings. Otherwise, *m* is added to the list of maximal matchings.

The following code can be improved to be more efficient in many ways. One way is to check before adding to the list of partial matchings. indeed, the list will contain partial matchings which represent the same one (i.e., [{i,j},{u,v}] and [{u,v},{i,j}] ).

```
import networkx as nx
import itertools

def all_maximal_matchings(T):

    maximal_matchings = []
    partial_matchings = [{(u,v)} for (u,v) in T.edges()]

    while partial_matchings:
        # get current partial matching
        m = partial_matchings.pop()
        nodes_m = set(itertools.chain(*m))

        extended = False
        for (u,v) in T.edges():
            if u not in nodes_m and v not in nodes_m:
                extended = True
                # copy m, extend it and add it to the list of partial matchings
                m_extended = set(m)
                m_extended.add((u,v))
                partial_matchings.append(m_extended)

        if not extended and m not in maximal_matchings:
            maximal_matchings.append(m)

    return maximal_matchings

T = nx.Graph()

T.add_edge('A','B')
T.add_edge('A','C')
T.add_edge('B','D')
T.add_edge('D','A')

print(all_maximal_matchings(T))
```

Comment: No, that's not what I'm looking for. if I print the output, it is: [{('B', 'D'), ('A', 'C')}, {('A', 'D')}, {('A', 'B')}] Notice that in the second dictionary of the list A appears in both matchings. If A is really person D, then A can't be person B.

Comment: The output is a list that consists of 3 sets {(B,D),(A,C)},  {(A,B)}  and {(A,D)} and it's the same of your example. If it's not what you are looking for, I misread the question.

Comment: Ah youre right - that's what I need! Thanks! I saw them as one item. If you do some trivial edit to your answer I'll change my downvote to an upvote.